# SqlDataReader Index Out Of Range Exception when correct column count is returned

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that returns correct column count, but the code below works most of the times, but **RANDOMLY** throws exception below. We had upgraded to .NET 4.6 recently, and we notice the exception afterwards.

**Questions:**

1 Where and why does the exception occur?

2 Based on source code at the bottom, how is it possible that SQL client receives empty metaData from server side?

Stored procedure `GetUser`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUser]    
    @UserID int
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @UserIDChar NVARCHAR(255);
    SET @UserIDChar = convert(nvarchar(255), @UserID);

    SELECT TOP 1
        A.Value1 As FirstName, 
        A.Value2 As LastName
       -- three more columns omitted here
    FROM dbo.Activity as A      
    WHERE A.ActivityValue = @UserIDChar  --ActivityValue is NVARCHAR(255) type
    ORDER BY A.DateCreated DESC 

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

END
```

C# web layer:

```
using (var cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "GetUser";  //the proc returns one row that consists of two columns
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", userId);

    cn.Open();

    using (IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult))
    {
        if (dr.Read())  //check if row is available
        {
            string firstName = (string)dr[0];
            string lastName = (string)dr[1];                        
            // three more columns omitted here
            return firstName + " " + lastName;
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> Exception Type: System.IndexOutOfRangeException
>   Message: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>   Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
>   TargetSite: Void CheckDataIsReady(Int32, Boolean, Boolean, System.String)
>   Source: System.Data

### Source Code below:

```
private void CheckDataIsReady(int columnIndex, bool allowPartiallyReadColumn = false, bool permitAsync = false, string methodName = null) {
            if (_isClosed) {
                throw ADP.DataReaderClosed(methodName ?? "CheckDataIsReady");
            }
            if ((!permitAsync) && (_currentTask != null)) {
                throw ADP.AsyncOperationPending();
            }
            Debug.Assert(!_sharedState._dataReady || _metaData != null, "Data is ready, but there is no metadata?");
            if ((!_sharedState._dataReady) || (_metaData == null)) {
                throw SQL.InvalidRead();
            }
            if ((columnIndex < 0) || (columnIndex >= _metaData.Length)) {
                throw ADP.IndexOutOfRange();
            }
            if ((IsCommandBehavior(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)) &&                                    // Only for sequential access
                ((_sharedState._nextColumnDataToRead > columnIndex) || (_lastColumnWithDataChunkRead > columnIndex) ||   // Read past column
                ((!allowPartiallyReadColumn) && (_lastColumnWithDataChunkRead == columnIndex)) ||           // Partially read column
                ((allowPartiallyReadColumn) && (HasActiveStreamOrTextReaderOnColumn(columnIndex))))) {      // Has a Stream or TextReader on a partially-read column
                    throw ADP.NonSequentialColumnAccess(columnIndex, Math.Max(_sharedState._nextColumnDataToRead, _lastColumnWithDataChunkRead + 1));
            }
        }
```

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs,577d642dce99ed0d

Comment: `TOP` *without* an explicit `ORDER BY` is pointless - which `TOP 1` row do you expect to get?? Without an explicit ordering, it's arbitrary - you'll just get back one, more or less randomly chosen row from your table ......

Comment: Have you tried specifying the column header as opposed to the index? string firstName = dr["FirstName"];

Comment: You probably need `SET NOCOUNT ON`  in your stored proc. What might be happening is that the number of records is being returned and not the result of the `SELECT`.

Comment: @Igor how would that effect the results ?

Comment: Your code looks fine.  Try this. temporarily remove your string setters...and use this :   object val1 = dr[0];  object val2 = dr[1];  then see if they are actually strings

Comment: try using the direct select statement with out using the stored procedure

Comment: also, i think there is a dr.FieldCount property you can look at.                  int fc = dr.FieldCount;

Comment: Its possible that your script is actually returning nothing and you are trying to retrieve an index of an empty dataset, that would explain why you are getting an index out of range exception.

Comment: @Kendo - wouldn't `dr.Read()` return false though in that scenario.

Comment: @igor yes it would, good point.

Comment: Please post your actual and complete stored procedure script for `GetUser`; Your `C#` code looks fine

Comment: @techspider updated

Comment: your c# code doesn't seem to be sending parameter. Is this latest code?

Comment: I believe you DON'T need `SET NOCOUNT OFF` at the end.

Comment: @techspider SET NOCOUNT OFF is set there.why do you say so?

Comment: @Pingpong Because [it will happen anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2271668/11683).

Comment: @GSerg, but it does NOT affect the result, does it?

Comment: Maybe it could be a bug in the db client: is it the most updated version? Is the connection lost after this error or still active for next command?

Comment: @Pingpong It shouldn't but I guess it might if that code is not the actual true final code. Anyhow you are referring to the source code of SqlDataReader where it explicitly throws `IndexOutOfRangeException` when `(columnIndex < 0) || (columnIndex >= _metaData.Length)`, so I assume `_metaData.Length` is `0`.

Comment: @Gerg why _metaData.Length is 0?

Comment: @Machine Learning I don't notice connection lost. Will check it when I have the chance.

Comment: @Pingpong Because e.g. you are getting some informational message for a result without realising it? Try removing `CommandBehavior.SingleResult` and seeing how many results there are.

Comment: @GSerg "seeing how many results there are." what do you mean? I cannot change it without a reason, because it is on production and cannot replicate it now?

Comment: @GSerg columnIndex >= _metaData.Length, this tells me _metaData is smaller than index, which seems metadata is lost, as opposed to getting informational message like you said. Please tell me the reason.

Answer (score 0):

The lack of a schema name could be messin' with you.

Also, some debugging tips in the C# code below.

1. Supply a schema name for the stored procedure.

   ```
   IF EXISTS (
               SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
               WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = N'PROCEDURE' and ROUTINE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' and ROUTINE_NAME = N'GetUser'  
           )   
   BEGIN
       DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUser]
   END

   GO

   CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetUser()

   AS 

   SELECT TOP 1
       FirstName, LastName
   FROM 
       User
   --omitted WHERE userid = @id


   GO
   ```
2. Change your c# to:

   ```
      using (var cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
     {
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          cmd.CommandText = "dbo.GetUser";  
          cmd.Connection = cn;

          cn.Open();

          using (IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
          {
          while (dr.Read()) 
                              string temp = string.Empty;

       int fc = dr.FieldCount;    
       if (fc>0)
       {
                       object val2 = dr[0];
                       temp = val1.GetType().ToString();
       }

       if (fc>1)
       {
                       object val2 = dr[1];
                       temp = val2.GetType().ToString();
       }



       temp = "did I get here?";

       string firstName = (string)dr[0];
       string lastName = (string)dr[1];                        

       return firstName + " " + lastName;
   }
          }
          }
   ```

Comment: Only one schema exists, which is dbo

Comment: I need to know why the exception occurs.

Comment: Did you run the c# code (my version) .. without the schema name?

Comment: Note, I'm *not* using an overloaded .ExecuteReader() method. And the code is looking at the FieldCount and the datatypes of the returned rows. If you get the above code to work (which I think it will).......then you need to focus on the overload. System.Data.Commandbehavior.SingleRow would be my next step.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is messing you up in your stored procedure:

A.Value2 Ad LastName

Should be:
A.Value2 as LastName

Comment: I think it is a typo in question

Comment: it is a typo like ~techspider said

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specify parameter `userid` in C# code please use `CommandParameter` and then try to do

Comment: as in the comment, it is commented out for simplicity. sorry about that.

Comment: Have you tried again to check what result it shows after removing CommandBehavior.SingleResult may be metadata contain 0 value

Comment: if again throwing exception then you have to re define schema of the table because your code looks good

Comment: Why metadata contains 0 value after CommandBehavior.SingleResult   is removed?

Comment: Why I have to re define schema of the table? Please tell me the reasoning behind it.

Comment: Index out of index exception comes when data reader didn't find column index in your case your column index <0.Following link can be useful in your case [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/166171/Index-Out-Of-Range-Exception)
 [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74a5db87-c63f-4386-b317-e848dedb2cd9/sqldatareadergetordinal-fails-rarely-with-indexoutofrange?forum=adodotnetdataproviders)

Comment: I hard coded index of 0, and 1. Why do you say index <0?

Comment: you hard coded the index but data reader is not getting the index that why the error as you try to fetch 0 index but it is not available in datareader please look at the link above for reference in comment may solve what you are missing

Comment: Can you tell me which section on the link above? Because I cannot see the relevant section for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try
Might not fix but you will get information and at least it will fail gracefully

```
try
{ 
    cn.Open();
    string firstName = "not";
    string lastName = "found";
    using (SQLDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult))
    {
        if (dr.Read())  //if there is a row, there are two columns. Thus index is used below
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(dr.FieldCount);
            firstName = rdr.IsDBNull(0) ? string.Empty : rdr.GetString(0);
            lastName = rdr.IsDBNull(1) ? string.Empty : rdr.GetString(1);                         
        }
    }
} 
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("GetUser " + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("GetUser" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    cn.Close();
}
return firstName + " " + lastName;
```